Using random samples from indistinguishable ensembles to create new empirical ensembles
Suppose I have two computationally indistinguishable ensembles of random variables $\{X_i\}_i$ and $\{Y_i\}_i$ ($i$ is the usual security parameter). The random variables are both uniformly distributed and may have exponentially many outcomes.
Let's say I have an algorithm that has access to some oracle that allows me to sample $X_i$ and $Y_i$ (for some large enough $i$) a polynomial number of times $m$.
I now store in my memory the two polynomial size vectors $\bar{x} = (x_0,x_1,...,x_m)$ and $\bar{y}= (y_0,y_1,...,y_m)$.
I want to use these saved values as a new PRG by giving out random samples from $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$.
Now, if some (PPT) distinguisher $D$ cannot distinguish one outcome from $X_i$ or $Y_i$ (by assumption of indistinguishability of the ensembles), then, if I give it a sample from $\bar{x}$ or $\bar{y}$ instead, they won't be able to distinguish also.
But what happens if I allow $D$ to access a polynomial amount of samples (say $n$)?
By assumption, it cannot distinguish $X_i$ or $Y_i$, but $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ have a limited amount of samples in memory. If $D$ can query at most $m$ times, then I can keep a counter and give a different sample each time. But if $n>m$, there is the possibility that $D$ can see the same sample twice (or more, even polynomial, times).
However, the algorithm $D(\bar{x})$ and $D(\bar{y})$ are essentially two Bernoulli random variables that outputs $0$ or $1$ to guess $\bar{x}$ or $\bar{y}$.
So, the probabiilty of some $D$ outputing $0$ or $1$ with high probabiliy on $n$ samples of $\bar{x}$ or $\bar{y}$ seems to be the weighted sum (but all weights are the same) of Bernoulli random variables (the $n$ guesses).
By Hoeffding's inequality, this should converge to the expected value exponentially fast, and thus it would be the same (except for an exponentially low error) as distinguishing the original $X_i$ and $Y_i$.
I have two questions:

1: Is the expected value of $D(x)$ equal when $x$ is sampled from $X_i$ or $\bar{x}$?
2: Can I show that indistinguishability of $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ holds or does not hold? If so, how?


Hiya!  Err, in terms of sampling, what's the usual security parameter?

Hello @PaulUszak, here $i$ could be the bit-length of the samples from $X_i$ and $Y_i$.

Don't see how 64 bit doubles are more "secure" than raw bytes.

Considering just the definition of $\bar{x}, \bar{y}$ and ypur questions the answers are:

1: Yes, the expected value is the same as the distribution of $X_i$ is identical to the random process "sample independently $m$ values from $X_i$ and then return (in whatever way) one of these samples". Note, however, in cryptography we more commonly speak of the probability of an algorithm doing something (like "the probability of $D$ outputting $1$") instead of its expected value.
(Edit: This holds only for a single sampled value. For more samples, this does of course not hold)
2: Yes, you can show that $\bar{x}, \bar{y}$ are computationally indistinguishable random variables just like their "parents" $X,Y$. This is usually proven using a so called Hybrid argument. This proof strategy is explained in detail in this publication of Fischlin and Mittelbach (concretely, this statement is considered in Lemma 3.1 and its proof).

Besides answering the concrete questions, I list some of the issues I had with your description. In order to deepen your understanding you should probably consider them:

It gives the algorithm $D$ no additional power or information when it obtains the same sample a second or $k$-th time. So, making a distinction between adversaries making $n\leq m$ or $n>m$ queries is not necessary here.
Your model is not fully clear (to me). Is it an interactive game, where $D$ adaptively queries for further samples? Or is it given a fixed number of samples? Formalize what you analzye.
As the model is unclear, it is also unclear (to me) what you mean with the (equally) weighted sum over the Bernoulli variables for samples. Be aware that you cannot make any assumption on the internal behaviour of $D$ when considering computational indistinguishability. $D$ may query $m$ times but only use its first sample for computing its output. Or just choose the number $m$ it wants to query and then disregard the samples and output $1$ with probability $1/m$. Or... Whatever. $D$ is a black box (and that's what we usually consider in crypto, though in certain scenarios white box approaches are required/used)


Thank you for your answer, it was very clear. But I still have some questions.

I read Lemma 3.1. It assumes that you have a vector of polynomial length where each entry is a random variable. In my case it's quite different, I have a vector whose entries are each one sample of a random variable, and then I choose an index at random and return that sample.
I don't understand why $n\leq m$ is the same as $n>m$. If $m=1$ (the vectors $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ have a single sample. Sampling $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ many times returns always the same sample. Shouldn't this help to distinguish?


1: It's not (too) different. Indeed, you can easily reduce your case to the other case. Construct an algorithm $D'$ which obtains $n$ independent samples $(z_1,\dots,z_n)$ directly and then answers the queries of $D$ by choosing uniformly an index $j$ and returning $z_j$. (Also note: You have a vector of polynomial length with random variables as entries, too. But you additionally randomize its return process).
2: How should this help to distinguish? If I tell you "the first sample was 5" and then tell this to you over and over again, this does not give you any further information.

I will try to work out the proof of Lemma 3.1 adapting to my case, thank you! But sorry to keep asking more questions: if my vector has $m$ samples from $X$, these samples are fixed values from the range of $X$, are they random variables as well? Also, I agree that giving me the sample $5$ over and over again does not help to distinguish $X$ from $Y$. But in this case of $m=1$, I now have created one new RV $\bar{x}$ that always outputs (say) $5$ (a possible outcome of $X$) and another RV $\bar{y}$ that always outputs (say) $3$ (a possible outcome of $Y$). Are they not distinguishable?

After fixing something, it is not random anymore. Note, it is utterly different whether you ask "Let $x$ and $y$ be fixed vectors consisting of $n$ samples from $X$ and $Y$, is there a ppt algorithm $D$ which distinguishes between both" or "is there a ppt $D$ which distinguishes your processes". The former usually makes no sense: Unless $x=y$ there is a ppt $D$ which distinguishes with probability $1$ (and with overwhelming probability when it's queries are answered with random entries). For your concrete example, $D$ on input $5$ outputs $0$ and on input $3$ outputs $1$ => Distinguished!

I think, a valuable advice is also: Before working out the proof, you should really reflect and flesh out the model and definitions which you are considering! Especially, as sketched, the order in which things are handled is important!

I agree that the vectors of $\bar{x},\bar{y}$ are not random anymore, but I'm defining a new sampling that returns random elements of $\bar{x},\bar{y}$. If these vectors only have one entry they are distinguishable. But I'm randomly chosing from $\bar{x},\bar{y}$ that have polynomial nr of elements. I believe it is important as elements are samples from $X$ and $Y$, and the expected value over this sampling of elements of $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ is the same expected value over sampling from $X$ and $Y$ (original Q1). But I can't show that $X\approx Y$ implies or not $\bar{x}\approx \bar{y}$.

Any fixed vectors $\bar{x},\bar{y}$ would be distinguishable for any polynomial number $n$ of samples, if they disagree on just one of these sampled values: With (non-negligible) probability $1/n$ your process will sample exactly this value. So the distinguisher would be correct with probability at least $1/n$. Fixing those vectors before fixing the distinguisher leads to a non/less meaningful notion of distinguishability...
